# Salto de linea de un contenido parrafo en un popup?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente código que dinámicamente pone unas imágenes arrastrables en encima de otra imagen con un `popup`. Pero, al tener un contenido en el `<p>` grande por ejemplo: sensor 1 2 3 4, 1234 se va a otra linea y quiero que siga en la misma linea, si le quito la posicion absoluta me descuadra todo lo que ya he trabajado y por supuesto que no podre moverlo.

Código:

```css
   .info {
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   left: calc(100% + 1em);
   top: 43%;
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 0.1em 5em;
   border-radius: 2.2em;
   font-family: arial;
   background: #DEDEDE;
   color: #362e2e;
   transition: all ease .3s;
   transform: translateX(-62%) translateY(-140%);
}

.img-sensor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#plano {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px/9;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px ridge;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>Algo de texto aquí para ver el problema</p>

<div id="contenido-plano">
  <div id="plano">
    <img class="img-sensor" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/eee">
    <div style="top:92px; left:100px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor1 2 3 4</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:359px; left:252px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="3">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor2</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:252px; left:571px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="4">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor3</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shaz la imagen tiene una div que tiene 800x600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es "forzar" a que el texto se mantenga en una línea, puedes usar:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Esta propiedad determina como se deben "comportar" los espacios en blanco en un elemento, en este caso, el valor nowrap elimina los saltos de línea.

```css
.info {
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   left: calc(100% + 1em);
   top: 43%;
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 0.1em 5em;
   border-radius: 2.2em;
   font-family: arial;
   background: #DEDEDE;
   color: #362e2e;
   transition: all ease .3s;
   white-space: nowrap ;
   text-align: center;
}

.img-sensor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#plano {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px/9;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px ridge;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="contenido-plano">
  <div id="plano">
    <img class="img-sensor" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/eee">
    <div style="top:30px; left:100px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor1 45 64545 454545</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:359px; left:252px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="3">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor2</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:252px; left:571px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="4">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor3</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me funciona pero, como hago para que los botones siempre queden al centro del parrafo? @Shaz

Comment: Agrega `text-align: center;` a `.info`, revisa mi actualización.

Answer (score 2):

Dos consejos, prueba ponerle una medida mínima en `em` al `p`, así:

```
p{
  min-width: 8em;
  text-align: center; /*Para que estén al centro del parrafo*/
}
```

y para evitar la separación por los espacios en blanco, es:

```
p{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Prueba y nos cuentas. Ejemplo:

```css
.info {
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   left: calc(100% + 1em);
   top: 43%;
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 0.1em 5em;
   border-radius: 2.2em;
   font-family: arial;
   background: #DEDEDE;
   color: #362e2e;
   transition: all ease .3s;
   transform: translateX(-62%) translateY(-140%);
}

.img-sensor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#plano {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px/9;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px ridge;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.info > p:first-child{
  min-width: 8em
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>Algo de texto aquí para ver el problema</p>

<div id="contenido-plano">
  <div id="plano">
    <img class="img-sensor" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/eee">
    <div style="top:92px; left:100px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor1 2 3 4</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:359px; left:252px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="3">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor2</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:252px; left:571px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="4">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor3</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aquí lo mismo pero con `white-space: nowrap`

La razón que te digo que lo combines con un tamaño mínimo, es por que veo que usas mucho posicionamiento absoluto con pixeles, esto evita ciertos problemas futuros; *Edit* como lo del centrado que mencionas en la otra respuesta.

```css
.info {
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   left: calc(100% + 1em);
   top: 43%;
   font-size: .8em;
   padding: 0.1em 5em;
   border-radius: 2.2em;
   font-family: arial;
   background: #DEDEDE;
   color: #362e2e;
   transition: all ease .3s;
   transform: translateX(-62%) translateY(-140%);
}

.img-sensor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
}

.sensor {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#plano {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px/9;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 1px ridge;
  border-color: gainsboro;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.info > p:first-child{
  min-width: 8em;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p>Algo de texto aquí para ver el problema</p>

<div id="contenido-plano">
  <div id="plano">
    <img class="img-sensor" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/eee">
    <div style="top:92px; left:100px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="1">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor1 2 3 4</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(1)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:359px; left:252px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="3">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor2</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(3)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
    <div style="top:252px; left:571px;" class="sensor ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-id="4">
      <div class="info">
        <p>Sensor3</p>
        <a title="Editar Sensor" id="editar-sensor" onclick="EditarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
        <a title="Eliminar Sensor" id="elimnar-sensor" onclick="EliminarSensor(4)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-erase"></i></a>
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/20/0a0" width="20">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```